# can we enable MFA for an IAM account using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

We are managing our iam user accounts using terraform and we're checking the possibility of enabling MFA for each of these accounts.

Is it possible to enable MFA using terraform ?

Comment: What do you mean by enable MFA for the account? Do you mean add an MFA device to the user account? Or do you mean to enforce their usage of the MFA device when performing API calls?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I meant adding MFA device to the user account. is this something that we could manage via terraform or is it something that we need to do manually ?

Comment: This isn't something exposed over the API. With TOTP based MFA, when you enroll an MFA device in the console, AWS will provide the secret key (normally in the form of a QR code that you scan with your Virtual MFA device such as Google Authenticator app) and then ask for a couple of responses in a row to make sure that it is correctly synced. With U2F you need the browser to enroll the hardware key and then it will handle challenge. What is you issue with allowing users to enroll MFA devices through the console once the user is created?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR there is no issue actually. I was concerned about doing manual changes on the resources created using terraform. In general it's advised not to do any manual changes to the resources managed using terraform right?. Is that not applicable in this case ?

Comment: Yeah it's fine here because it's not something that Terraform (or indeed anything other than the console) can manage. Also you can edit things outside of Terraform but Terraform will then go and undo those changes if you don't put those changes back into your Terraform code.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR great thanks a lot! it really gave me lot of insight